# Form Array all controls conditional required validation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have form Array , which controls has to be required , based on a variable ,now I wrote custom validator like below

```
  recurringValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      if (!control.value) {
        return null;
      }
      if (this.myVariable === 'constant1') {
        return Validators.required;
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

now this will check the value of the 'myVariable' and put required but somehow its not working , I am adding this custom validators like below

```
const fbGroup = this.fb.group({
  recurringControl1: this.fb.control('', [this.recurringValidator()]),
  recurringControl2: this.fb.control('', [this.recurringValidator()]),
  recurringControl3: this.fb.control('', [this.recurringValidator()])
});

   this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      control1: fb.control('', [this.recurringValidator()]),
      groupcontrol1: fb.array([])
    });
```

when I click on submit , form is valid when even `myVariable` value is `'constant1'` .
any suggestion or modifications please .

here is the stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-validators?

Comment: any special reason you are return `Validators.requred` from async validator function ? @Shaswata

Comment: depnding on the variable value , it can be not required also ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the validator reference instead of executing and returning the value. If you were to use the validator directly, that would be the correct way to do it, but since you are using your custom validator, the validator will be called by Angular (your validator) but for the required validator, you are the one who need to invoke it, so try replacing:

```
recurringValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (!control.value) {
      return null;
    }
    if (this.myVariable === 'constant1') {
      return Validators.required;
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

To:

```
recurringValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    // if (!control.value) {
    //   return null;
    // }
    if (this.myVariable === 'constant1') {
      // Invoking the validator ourselves
      return Validators.required(control);
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

Also, I don't see the need for the first condition `!control.value`, that will always return null for empty values no matter the content of `myVariable`, so I commented out.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-validators?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You can not return a Validator, else an object and make a custom validator

If your variable not change with the time you can do

```
recurringValidator(necesary:boolean): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      if (control.value) { //<--if has any value return null
        return null;
      }
      if (necesary) {
        return {required:true} //<--see that you return an object, NOT Validators.required
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

And you use

```
control=new FormControl(null,this.recurringValidator(this.myVariable!='constant1'))
```

See that, if you change the value of `myVariable`**after** create the formControl, **not** work, the validator get the actual value of the variable

If you need take account the variable and the variable change in the time you need use "bind(this)" when you create the form

```
recurringValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      if (control.value) {
        return null;
      }
      if (this.myVariable === 'constant1') {
        return {required:true} //<--see that you return an object, NOT Validators.required
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

And use

```
control=new FormControl(null,this.recurringValidator().bind(this))
```

In this case, when you change the variable don't forget updateAndValidity the control, e.g.

```
<button (click)="myVariable=!myVariable;
                control.updateValueAndValidity()">
    click
</button>
```